# TinyMCE image as link

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, tinymce

I am using [TinyMCE](https://www.tinymce.com/) in an application and having trouble with what seems like something simple.  I need to add an image that links to a website.  I already have the link, image, and imagetools plugins working.  On the toolbar I have a link and image button.  However, neither of these options seem to have what I am looking for.  The link button forces text and the image button does not allow me to create a link out of it.

I have read thru the plugin section for both [Images](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/image/) and [Links](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/link/) so maybe I am missing something or this is just not possible.  I can add my own button on the toolbar and insert the content myself, but wanted to use the plugin tools if possible.

Here is a subset of my options section:

```
plugins: "link image imagetools",
imagetools_toolbar: "rotateleft rotateright | flipv fliph | editimage imageoptions",
content_css: "content/mce.css",
toolbar1: 'addlink | undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link | image',
```

Comment: If I insert an image, click once on the image and then click the insert link toolbar button I can place a hyperlink on the image.  Can you create a TinyMCE Fiddle that shows your configuration that is not allowing this behavior?

Comment: well......  that was easy.  I had never thought that the two could be used together on the image....  If you want to create an answer I will accept it for anybody else that misses this simple piece of information

Comment: Done.  Glad this was a simple resolution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I insert an image, click once on the image and then click the insert link toolbar button I can place a hyperlink on the image.

Can you create a TinyMCE Fiddle that shows your configuration that is not allowing this behavior?

Comment: I follow the your guidelines,, its produce an error `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'setBaseAndExtent' on 'Selection': There is no child at offset 1.`

Comment: @HamzaZafeer Got same error, updating tinymce library to latest version solved the issue (the issue was related to Chrome) - https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/178625

Answer (score 0):

Hamza is correct, I have managed to bypass this error and allow links from images to work by commenting out the following lines from `tinymce.js`:

```js
if (node && node.tagName == 'IMG') {
    self.getSel().setBaseAndExtent(node, 0, node, 1);
}
```